# Keen slider continious autoplay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

I want the slider to move continuously without snapping. I've enabled `free mode` but on autoplay slides still snap. I searched the documentations but got no help. Is there any workaround for this?

Here's the slider with `autoplay` and `mode:"free"`. https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-tree-oy0fl?file=/script.js

Documentation for keen slider: https://keen-slider.io/api/#api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option was to adjust the slide times and autoplay times, heres my code:
(This code is from Keen slider's Free Mode example.)
Implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-tree-oy0fl?file=/script.js

```
var sliderElement = document.getElementById("my-keen-slider");
var interval = 0;

function autoplay(run) {
clearInterval(interval);
interval = setInterval(function () {
  if (run && slider) {
    slider.next();
  }
}, 3000);
}

var slider = new KeenSlider(sliderElement, {
loop: true,
mode: "free",
duration: 180000,
});

slider.next();
autoplay(true);
```

The part I edited is `duration: 180000` and `interval`'s interval (3000). This made it LOOK LIKE its continuously scrolling. Other answers are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I just did it in Next.js to auto play the slider:

```
const [sliderRef, slider] = useKeenSlider({
    loop: true,
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      slider?.current.next()
    }, 3000)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, [slider])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now a more robust way of achieving continuous autoplay in Keen-Slider, as mentioned in [this author comment](https://github.com/rcbyr/keen-slider/issues/74).

Taken from the [official example](https://keen-slider.io/examples#auto-move) (slightly tweaked to enable dragging):

```js
const animation = { duration: 40000, easing: (t) => t }

const slider = new KeenSlider('#my-keen-slider', {
  loop: true,
  renderMode: 'performance',
  drag: true,
  mode: 'free',
  slides: {perView: 3},
  created(s) {
    s.moveToIdx(5, true, animation)
  },
  updated(s) {
    s.moveToIdx(s.track.details.abs + 5, true, animation)
  },
  animationEnded(s) {
    s.moveToIdx(s.track.details.abs + 5, true, animation)
  },
})
```